# How to create a multi-colored NativeScript BarSeries stacked bar chart

Tags: nativescript

I am unable to create a stacked bar chart that has different colors for each BarSeries. Is this a limitation of the nativescript-ui RadChart component?

Here is the XML I'm using...

```
<chart:RadCartesianChart id="productionSummaryChart" height="200" loaded="onLoaded">
  <chart:RadCartesianChart.horizontalAxis>
    <chart:CategoricalAxis/>
  </chart:RadCartesianChart.horizontalAxis>
  <chart:RadCartesianChart.verticalAxis>
    <chart:LinearAxis/>
  </chart:RadCartesianChart.verticalAxis>
  <chart:RadCartesianChart.series>
    <chart:BarSeries seriesName="Bar1" items="{{ data1 }}" stackMode="Stack" paletteMode="Item" categoryProperty="key" valueProperty="value"/>
    <chart:BarSeries seriesName="Bar2" items="{{ data2 }}" stackMode="Stack" paletteMode="Item" categoryProperty="key" valueProperty="value"/>
  </chart:RadCartesianChart.series>
  <chart:RadCartesianChart.palettes>
    <chart:Palette seriesName="Bar1">
      <chart:Palette.entries>
        <chart:PaletteEntry strokeColor="#F08080" fillColor="#F08080"/>
        <chart:PaletteEntry strokeColor="#D0D0D0" fillColor="#D0D0D0"/>
      </chart:Palette.entries>
    </chart:Palette>
    <chart:Palette seriesName="Bar2">
      <chart:Palette.entries>
        <chart:PaletteEntry strokeColor="#E09070" fillColor="#E09070"/>
        <chart:PaletteEntry strokeColor="#D0D0D0" fillColor="#D0D0D0"/>
      </chart:Palette.entries>
    </chart:Palette>
  </chart:RadCartesianChart.palettes>
</chart:RadCartesianChart>
```

And here is the TS code for the View...

```
var Observable = require('tns-core-modules/data/observable').Observable;

var viewModel = new Observable();
viewModel.data1 = [
  { key: "One", value: 10 },
  { key: "Two", value: 5 }
];
viewModel.data2 = [
  { key: "One", value: 7 },
  { key: "Two", value: 8 }
];

export function onLoaded(args) {
  var view = args.object;
  view.bindingContext = viewModel;
};
```

I expected to see the first stacked bar with 4 colors and the second stacked bar with the same color... but instead both stacked bars have a single color with the first stacked bar being the color specified for the last BarSeries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=JNnHkM) for you.

```
<chart:RadCartesianChart.palettes>
            <chart:Palette seriesName="Bar1">
                <chart:Palette.entries>
                    <chart:PaletteEntry strokeColor="Orange" fillColor="Yellow" />
                    <chart:PaletteEntry strokeColor="Pink" fillColor="Green" />
                    <chart:PaletteEntry strokeColor="red" fillColor="black" />
                </chart:Palette.entries>
            </chart:Palette>
            <chart:Palette seriesName="Bar2">
                <chart:Palette.entries>
                    <chart:PaletteEntry strokeColor="red" fillColor="blue" />
                    <chart:PaletteEntry strokeColor="red" fillColor="blue" />
                    <chart:PaletteEntry strokeColor="yellow" fillColor="green" />
                </chart:Palette.entries>
            </chart:Palette>
        </chart:RadCartesianChart.palettes>
```

and .ts

```
data1 = [
    { key: "One", value: 5 },
    { key: "Two", value: 5 },
    { key: "Three", value: 5 }
];
data2 = [
    { key: "One", value: 10 },
    { key: "Two", value: 8 },
    { key: "Three", value: 5 }
];
```

May be, something is wrong with your color codes and it is working absolutely fine with me on ios.

Comment: I have not yet tried it on an iOS device... just in the Android emulator. I'll try it on an iOS device and see if it works and is just an Android issue.

Comment: This appears to be a bug with the Android implementation or the Android Emulator. I'll mark this as the correct answer and open a bug report.